# Words not replacing correctly

Tags: java

I am writing a class that takes a dictionary and a txt file and if a word in the txt file isn't in the dictionary then it gives the user a chance to change the incorrect words. After the corrections are made, it will output the corrected txt file.

Here's an example txt file:

```
twinkx twinkx lottle star how I
lottle lamb its a warld of laughter a
warld of tears
```

For example, it would ask me if i wanted to correct twinkx, and when i switch it to twinkle, it would still output the same thing as above, with it still saying twinkx. That leads me to believe there is something wrong with my replacement method. The algorithm for it is described in the comments so I possibly could have missed something.

```
    private void replace(String misspelled, String replacement){
    //TODO: Algorithm:
    //If wrongWords contains the misspelled word:
    //   get ALL the lineNumbers on where the misspelled word appears
    //   for each line number where it appears:
    //        in fileLines[line] replace misspelled with replacement
    //        (Hint: use one of the available methods in the String class to do the replacement)
    if(wrongWords.containsKey(misspelled))
       wrongWords.get(misspelled);
       for(String line : fileLine){
          line.replace(misspelled, replacement);
       }  
    }
```

Here is the method that calls replace in the first place:

```
private Scanner scan; // a Scanner to read user's input
private HashSet<String> dictionary;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> wrongWords;
private ArrayList<String> fileLine;


private void correctionMode(){   
  //for each line in fileLines:
  //   for each word in the line:
  //      if the word is in wrongWords:
  //            display the word and ALL the line numbers it appears on
  //            ask user if they like to replace?(y/n)
  //            if user chooses y: 
  //              ask for a new word and call the replace method replaceAll occurrences
  //            for either y or n delete word from wrongWords     
  //Hint: for parsing lines look back at the processFile()
  for(String line: fileLine)
    for(String w: line.split("\\s"))
       if(wrongWords.containsKey(w)){
           System.out.println(w + " " + wrongWords.get(w));
           System.out.println("replace all? (y or n): ");
           String r = scan.nextLine();
           if(r.equals("y")){
              System.out.println("Enter replacement: ");
              String r2 = scan.nextLine();
              replace(w, r2);
              wrongWords.remove(w);
           }
           else if(r.equals("n")){
              wrongWords.remove(w);
           }              
       }                        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line is only a loop variable. You need something like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fileLine.size(); i++) {
        fileLine.set(i, fileLine.get(i).replace(misspelled, replacement));
    }
```